# JQuery add Image to Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to create a plugin for jQuery, but there is a problem.

This is the .html:
http://pastebin.com/amLSFSZX

and this is the .js file:
http://pastebin.com/CmrHzKRk

I want 4 arrows in a div.

1. Top Middle
2. Right Middle
3. Bottom Middle
4. Left Middle

If it's not packed in a plugin it works fine.

But if I include the plugin, it bugs.

This is the output via Firebug:

```
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-top.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="height: 26px; width: 20px; top: 50px; left: 480480px; position: absolute; display: none;">
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-right.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-bottom.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="left: 480480px; position: absolute; display: none;">
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-left.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="height: 20px; width: 26px; top: 50250px; left: 480px; position: absolute; display: none;">
```

Can anyone help? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: To share html/css/js code snippets online, use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, here is it:
http://jsfiddle.net/2GzjB/

Answer (score 1):

It could be just a copy/paste or other mistake, but your inline styles output by firebug look odd in a few places.

You have `left: 480480px;` in two places and `top: 50250px`. You haven't explained exactly what is not happening or what the desired behavior is beyond 'it bugs'.

Regarding your jsfiddle, thanks for pulling those resources together, but when I first execute run on it there are already two errors which show up in my Developer Tools. arrow.js is not found and that you can't call method AddArrow on #map. You're probably using jQuery so you'll need to pick that as your framework on the left-hand side of the window.

But I think those odd left and top aspects might be causing the `bugs` that you were referring to.

**Edit**: It looks like your problem is that you are including the arrow.js plug-in but then overriding it yourself. At first glance arrow.js and the code in your javascripting area looks identical. (*Of course, they both shared the problem of not having parentheses around your calculations!*)

I have removed relying on arrow.js in my fiddle and I think *you should too* since you apparently are copying the code into your mark-up. If you don't have control over arrow.js then you **should be** using your own code because arrow.js is **flawed** when it doesn't put parentheses around the calculations of top and left.

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6nmR/7/) with basic arrows taken from the greater `Internet` (since I don't have access to your arrows). Stop relying on arrow.js; correct it as I have described, and you will be in a better place. The answer to your question of why everything breaks when you include the plugin is that the plugin is wrong.

You will need to adjust the code to execute it properly in your context. For example: jsfiddle fires $(document).ready() for you.

Comment: Hey, so. I have a div, and i want to add 4 arrows.
Here is an example: http://s7.directupload.net/images/120418/dwlhs78z.jpg

When the jquery code is directly in the .html file, it works fine. 
But when i create a plugin, it gives me some strange bugs, like left: 480480px; top: 50250px; etc.

here is a new link http://jsfiddle.net/Q6nmR/3/

Comment: I would suggest that you use Firebug to manually step through your javascript logic and look at the values that are getting pulled in from your o object. There are lots of places for `pos.top + height - o.ArrowHeight` to go wrong -- and you almost certainly want to put parenthesis around your arithmetic operations; otherwise your javascript could just be outputting 480480 instead of (480-480)=0

Comment: @Lizzaran; I have updated my answer and believe that should answer some of your questions. The plugin is flawed if I'm looking at the right one (arrow.js). Just take that code and bend it to your whims is my suggestion.